# How to redirect /page/index/About-Us/ to /About-Us

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect

- /page/index/About-Us/

link created in codeigniter framework to

- /About-Us

where the word 'About-Us' is dynamically created and can be any word may be 'contact-us' the next time.

How can I do it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in htaccess in the root :

```
RedirectMatch ^/page/index/(.+)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [routes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples). At the end of `APPPATH . 'config/routes.php'` file write:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

Comment: I have done as you suggested but the page says 404 Page not found.